# How often to run getWritableDatabase() and getReadableDatabase()?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm writing a Service, a Content Provider, and multiple apps. The Service writes new data to the Content Provider's SQLite database every 5 minutes or so plus at user input, and is intended to run pretty much forever in the background. The app, when running, will display data pulled from the Content Provider, and will be refreshed whenever the Service puts more data into the Content Provider's database.

Given that the Service only inserts into the database once every five minutes, when is the right time to call SQLiteOpenHelper's `getWritableDatabase()` / `getReadableDatabase()`? Is it on the `onCreate()` of the Content Provider, or should I run it every time there is an `insert()` and close it at the end of `insert()`? The data being inserted every 5 minutes will contain multiple inserts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With respect to your specific question, if you are going to use a `ContentProvider` this way, you may wish to go the open-and-close-every-insert pattern. There is no `onDestroy()` hook in `ContentProvider`, so there's no great time to close the database. With more frequent/random access patterns, you just have to live with it. In your case, you may as well close it up.

That being said, I'm not clear why you're bothering with a `ContentProvider` in the first place.

Comment: From my understanding, it's how you can share data across apps - I'm planning to write multiple apps that use the same data. (I suppose another way could be to attach the data to the service and have each app query the service, but I'm not sure what the advantages and disadvantages of each option will be.)

Comment: @jawonlee: Ah, sorry, you didn't mention the multiple-apps part in your question.