# Difference between getWritableDatabase() and getReadableDatabase()?

Tags: android, database

I use reading and writing to the database without any problems . But I can not find out the difference. I searched on Internet but it 's not quite clear. Can anyone tell me the difference? In which case should I use `getWritableDatabase()` or `getReadableDatabase()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [getWritableDatabase() VS getReadableDatabase()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597277/getwritabledatabase-vs-getreadabledatabase)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066318/how-often-to-run-getwritabledatabase-and-getreadabledatabase

Comment: I read it, But I cant not find the different and the conclusion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597277/getwritabledatabase-vs-getreadabledatabase

Comment: @oers : Thank you because of fixing my poor English.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getWritableDatabase() VS getReadableDatabase()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597277/getwritabledatabase-vs-getreadabledatabase)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check the [Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getReadableDatabase%28%29)

### public synchronized SQLiteDatabase getReadableDatabase ()

Since: API Level 1

> Create and/or open a database. This will be the same object returned
>   by getWritableDatabase() unless some problem, such as a full disk,
>   requires the database to be opened read-only. In that case, a
>   read-only database object will be returned. If the problem is fixed, a
>   future call to getWritableDatabase() may succeed, in which case the
>   read-only database object will be closed and the read/write object
>   will be returned in the future.

Like getWritableDatabase(), this method may take a long time to return, so you should not call it from the application main thread, including from ContentProvider.onCreate().
Returns

```
a database object valid until getWritableDatabase() or close() is called.
```

Throws
SQLiteException     if the database cannot be opened

### public synchronized SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase ()

Since: API Level 1

> Create and/or open a database that will be used for reading and
>   writing. The first time this is called, the database will be opened
>   and onCreate(SQLiteDatabase), onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase, int, int)
>   and/or onOpen(SQLiteDatabase) will be called.
>
> Once opened successfully, the database is cached, so you can call this
>   method every time you need to write to the database. (Make sure to
>   call close() when you no longer need the database.) Errors such as bad
>   permissions or a full disk may cause this method to fail, but future
>   attempts may succeed if the problem is fixed.

Database upgrade may take a long time, you should not call this method from the application main thread, including from ContentProvider.onCreate().
Returns

```
a read/write database object valid until close() is called
```

Throws
SQLiteException     if the database cannot be opened for writing

Comment: @tai.tran2008 look first para: **This(getReadableDatabase ()) will be the same object returned by getWritableDatabase() unless some problem, such as a full disk, requires the database to be opened read-only**. So, use **getReadableDatabase()** if you want to read only as name makes it simplified to understand what you want.

Answer (score 22):

Taken from my deleted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11752279/444761) (this question is a duplicate of that one).

> In normal situations, `getReadableDatabase()` will return the same
>   writable database returned by `getWritableDatabase()`.
>
> However, should it not be possible to return a writable database,
>   `getWritableDatabase()` will fail, whereas `getReadableDatabase()`
>   will attempt to return a `READ_ONLY` database.

Answer (score 3):

The different between two is the condition when disk become full. Both the `getReadableDatabase()` and `getWritableDatabase()` task is to open/create database.

But when the disk got full application crashes if you make a call to `getWritableDatabase()`. However, `getReadbleDatabase()` works fine in this case. Since, the `getReadableDatabase()` blocks write operations and allows Read operation.

Don't call these methods from applications main thread like from `onCreate()` method of `MainActivity` in Android or any callback methods.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is -

**getReadbleDatabase() -**

- Create and/or open a database. This will be the same object returned
  by getWritableDatabase() unless some problem, such as a full disk,
  requires the database to be opened read-only. In that case, a
  read-only database object will be returned. If the problem is fixed,
  a future call to getWritableDatabase() may succeed, in which case the
  read-only database object will be closed and the read/write object
  will be returned in the future.

**getWritableDatabase() -**

- Create and/or open a database that will be used for reading and
  writing. The first time this is called, the database will be opened
  and onCreate(SQLiteDatabase), onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase, int, int)
  and/or onOpen(SQLiteDatabase) will be called. Once opened
  successfully, the database is cached, so you can call this method
  every time you need to write to the database. (Make sure to call
  close() when you no longer need the database.) Errors such as bad
  permissions or a full disk may cause this method to fail, but future
  attempts may succeed if the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If your database crashes `GetReadableDatabase()` will return you a read/only object
while `GetWriteableDatabase()` will fail.